# 403 Forbidden error Spring-boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

I am creating a Web application with the spring-boot,rest api and angularjs but when I'm trying to  send $http.put request I'm getting 403 forbidden error. On triage I found that the Spring boot expects a CSRF Token and hence I'm trying to send the CSRF parameter from my Jsp page to the angularjs controller and In angularjs I'm trying to create a header with the csrf-token and trying to send this to my spring controller by I'm getting the same the error. If I disable the CSRF property in the spring security I'm able to execute the program without any issues.I'm new to this and hence could anyone help me in resolving this error.

The problem occurs in the viewProduct.jsp where I'm trying to call the addToCart($product.productId) angularjs function. It throws 403 Forbidden error

cart.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp"%>

<div class="container-wrapper">

<div class="container">
<section>
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
<h1>Cart</h1>

<p>All the selected products in your shopping cart</p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<section class="container" ng-app="cartApp">
<div ng-controller="cartCtrl" ng-init="initCartId(${cartId})">
<div class="btn btn-danger pull-left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Unit Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Action</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tr ng-repeat="item in cart.cartItems">
<td>{{item.product.productName}}</td>
<td>{{item.product.productPrice}}</td>
<td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
<td>{{item.totalPrice}}</td>
<td><a href="#" class="label label-danger" ng-click="removeCart(item.product.productId)">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>remove </a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th>Grand Total</th>
<th>{{cart.grandTotal}}</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</table>
<a href="<spring:url value="/productList"/>" class="btn btn-default">Continue Shopping</a>
</div>
</section>

</div>
</div>

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controller.js"/>"></script>

<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp"%>
```

viewProduct.jsp

```
    <%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp"%>
<div class="container-wrapper">


<div class="container">

<div class="page-header">
<h1>Product Detail</h1>
<p class="lead" >Detailed Product Information</p>
</div>
<div class="container" ng-app="cartApp">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-5">
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/${product.productId}.png"/>" alt="image" style="width: 100%;height: 300px"/>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-5">
<h3>${product.productName}</h3>
<p>${product.productDescription}</p>
<p><strong>Manufacturer </strong>${product.productManufacturer}</p>
<p><strong>Category </strong>${product.productCategory}</p>
<p><strong>Condition </strong>${product.productCondition}</p>
<h5><Strong>Price </Strong>${product.productPrice} USD</h5>
<br>

<c:set var="role" scope="page" value="${param.role}"/>
<c:set var="url" scope="page" value="/productList"/>
<c:if test="${role='admin'}">
<c:set var="url" scope="page" value="/admin/productInventory"></c:set>
</c:if>
<p ng-controller="cartCtrl">
<a href="<c:url value="${url}"/>" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
<a  class="btn btn-warning btn-large" ng-click="addToCart(${product.productId})">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">Order Now</span>
</a>
<a href="<c:url value="/cart"/>" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span> View Cart</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controller.js"/>"></script>

<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp"%>
```

contoller.js

```
/**
* Created by Dilipan on 6/26/2016.
*/

var cartApp =angular.module("cartApp",[]);


cartApp.config(function ($httpProvider){
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
})

cartApp.controller("cartCtrl",function ($scope,$http) {
$scope.refreshCart=function (cartId) {
$http.get("/eMusicStore/rest/cart/"+$scope.cartId).success(function (data) {
$scope.cart=data;
});
};

$scope.clearCart=function () {
$http.delete("/eMusicStore/rest/cart/"+$scope.cartId).success($scope.refreshCart(cartId));
};

$scope.initCartId=function (cartId) {
$scope.cartId=cartId;
$scope.refreshCart(cartId);
};
$scope.addToCart=function (productId,header,token) {


alert(token);

$http.put("/eMusicStore/rest/cart/add/"+productId,{csrf_token: token} ).success(function (data) {


$scope.refreshCart($http.get("/eMusicStore/rest/cart/cartId"));
alert("Product successfully added to the cart");
})
.error(function(data,status,header,config){
alert(data);
})
};
$scope.removeCart=function(productId){
$http.put("/eMusicStore/rest/cart/remove/"+productId).success(function(data){
$scope.refreshCart($http.get("/eMusicStore/rest/cart/cartId"));
});
};
});
```

security.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="Quackie14"></property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"   ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" >
    <list>
    <value>com.eMusicStore</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">

    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1024000"></property>
    </bean>

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:form-login
    login-page="/login"
    default-target-url="/admin/"
    authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
    login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
    username-parameter="username"
    password-parameter="password"

    />
    <security:logout
    logout-success-url="/login?logout"
    invalidate-session="true"
    logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
    />

    </security:http>
    <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider >
    <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
    authorities-by-username-query="select username,authority from authorities where username=?"
    users-by-username-query="SELECT  username,password,enabled from users where username=?"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    </beans>
```

cart-controller.java

```
package com.eMusicStore.controller;

import com.eMusicStore.dao.CartDao;
import com.eMusicStore.dao.ProductDao;
import com.eMusicStore.model.Cart;
import com.eMusicStore.model.CartItem;
import com.eMusicStore.model.Product;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

/**
* Created by Dilipan on 6/26/2016.
*/

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/cart")
public class CartController {


@Autowired
private CartDao cartDao;

@Autowired
private ProductDao productDao;

@RequestMapping(value="/{cartId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
Cart read(@PathVariable (value="cartId") String cartId)
{
return cartDao.readCart(cartId);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/{cartId}",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void updateCart(@PathVariable (value = "cartId")String cartId,@RequestBody Cart cart){
cartDao.updateCart(cartId,cart);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/{cartId}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void deleteCart(@PathVariable(value="cartId")String cartId){
cartDao.deleteCart(cartId);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add/{productId}",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)

public void addItems(@PathVariable(value="productId") int productId, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestHeader (value="csrf_token") CsrfToken _csrf){

String cartId= request.getSession().getId();
System.out.println(cartId);

Cart cart=cartDao.readCart(cartId);

if(cart==null){
cart=cartDao.createCart(new Cart(cartId));
}

Product product=productDao.getProductById(productId);
if(product==null){
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product Not available");
}

cart.addCartItems(new CartItem(product));

cartDao.updateCart(cartId,cart);
}
@RequestMapping(value="/remove/{productId}",method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void removeItems(@PathVariable(value="productId")int productID,HttpServletRequest request)
{
String cartId=request.getSession().getId();

Cart cart= cartDao.readCart(cartId);

if(cart==null){
cart=cartDao.createCart(new Cart(cartId));
}

Product product=productDao.getProductById(productID);

if(product==null){
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product Not available");
}

cart.removeCartItem(new CartItem(product));

cartDao.updateCart(cartId,cart);
}
@ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Illegal Request please verify your payload")
public void handlerClientError(Exception e){}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,reason = "Internal Server Error")
public void handlerServerError(Exception e){}

}
```

Comment: Please fix formatting and split the code into logically related pieces. Now it's unreadable.

Comment: Hi, Andrei I have formatted the logic and please do let me know in case of any additional information

Comment: You should configure spring security to accept AngularJS CSRF token.  This tutorial from spring explains in detail [https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii).  In special the section CSRF protection.